# Show event of public facebook page with graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the GRAPH API of Facebook to consume all events of some public page for my website...

I create a facebook app, get my token , appID & secret APP but when i try to consume events from the API for majority off publics pages an error message : 
"To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook"
But for other pages i can get some events but only 1 or 2 not more (some pages have 10 events).

But when i ask for facebook for approve my app they ask for lot of thing (like conenction button, or use case of my app)... In my case i need facebook app only for the token and i dont want to make one... Furthermore they ask for a complete application but my website needs this data to work so i have any issues to get this data..

Someone have an idea ??

Thanks

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/page/events, you should not be able to get page events at all: _“This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.”_